# Creating single app for normal screen and retina screen

Tags: air, retina-display

I am just very curious how to develop one app to fits normal screen and retina screen.

I mean like iPad 1, 2 mini and iPad 3, 4

Do you create two sets of image with different resolution?

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 1):

You can either develop app just to fit a normal screen - and on retina screens, the device will convert each pixel into a 2x2 pixel block.

Or create an adaptive layout - ie: the app lays out its objects to fit any size screen (within reason) - i believe "liquid layout" is the customary term.

Assuming you are not using Flex, if you want an adaptive layout you will have to implement one yourself.

Comment: so if you create the app just for retina display, and it won't work for normal screen?

Comment: not sure how non-retina devices will handle an oversized app - i assume they will scale it down to fit but ive never tried